# how to appear output at text area same like chatbot in jsp and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

I am doing a project regarding chatbot but the project using eclipse not AIML. I do not now how to appear a data that had been save in database oracle. `

ChatServlet

```
public class ChatServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String ChatBot = "/ChatBot.jsp";
    private static String HOME = "/Home.jsp";
    private ChatDAO dao;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */

     public ChatServlet() {
            super();
            dao = new ChatDAO();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }      
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String forward="";
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
            ChatInfo chat = new ChatInfo(); 

            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
            {
                int USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("USER_ID"));
                System.out.println(USER_ID);
                dao.deleteChat(USER_ID);
                forward = HOME;
                request.setAttribute("chats", dao.getAllChatDAO()); 
            }

            catch (Throwable theException) { 

                System.out.println(theException);
            }


    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ChatInfo chat = new ChatInfo();

        int USER_ID = 1;
        int ANSWER_ID = 1;

        chat.setANSWER(request.getParameter("answer"));
        chat.setUSER_ID(USER_ID);
        chat.setANSWER_ID(ANSWER_ID);

        chat = dao.add(chat);

        USER_ID++;
        ANSWER_ID++;

        response.sendRedirect("ChatBot.jsp");

    }
}
```

ChatBot.jsp

```
<div id = "container" align="left">
    <%  
        String ques = null;
        String[] OpenA = {"Apa yang membawa anda ke mari?","Apa yang boleh saya bantu?", "Bagaimana saya boleh bantu anda hari ini?"};
        List<String> listO = Arrays.asList(OpenA);
        Collections.shuffle(listO);
        for (String name : listO) {
            ques = name;
        }
        out.println("Dr.Anna : "+ ques);
     %>
    </div>

    <form action='ChatServlet' method="post">
    <div id = "controls">
        <textarea name = "answer" placeholder = "Enter your message here..."></textarea>
        <button type = "submit" value="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>chat</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ChatServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ChatServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ChatServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The data that i want to appear is at ChatBot.jsp.

Comment: Can u please be more specific on what you intend to receive ? Do you want the message that has been saved to be shown in textarea?

Comment: yes. i want the message appear.. @sathya

Comment: You mean the message you entered at "Enter your message here..." or with divID=controls , in the same place ?

Comment: If thats the case ,next time You will have the same answer in thew chat box

Comment: i want the message in "Enter your message here" to the text area id='container'.. It means that after i enter the message at the "Enter Your Message here" , the message will be save in oracle. then, the data from oracle, i want it to appear at the text area id='container'

Comment: @sathya what do you mean same answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use request dispatcher to have variables saved at request and to access the same request object at jsp as well

```
    int USER_ID = 1;
    int ANSWER_ID = 1;  
    chat.setANSWER(request.getParameter("answer"));
    chat.setUSER_ID(USER_ID);
    chat.setANSWER_ID(ANSWER_ID);

    chat = dao.add(chat);
    USER_ID++;
    ANSWER_ID++;
    String answer=   request.getParameter("answer");
    request.setAttribute("answer", answer);
    RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/ChatBot.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, resp);
```

In jsp follow these steps shown below in the program

```
            <div id = "container" align="left">
        <%  
        String ques = null;
        String[] OpenA = {"Apa yang membawa anda ke mari?","Apa yang boleh saya bantu?", "Bagaimana saya boleh bantu anda hari ini?"};
        List<String> listO = Arrays.asList(OpenA);
        Collections.shuffle(listO);
        for (String name : listO) {
            ques = name;

        }
        out.println("Dr.Anna : "+ ques);     
        String answer=(String)request.getAttribute("answer");
            if(answer !=null)
            out.print(answer);
         %>
        </div>

        <form action='ChatServlet' method="post">
        <div id = "controls">
        <textarea name = "answer" placeholder = "Enter your messagehere...">
       </textarea>
        <button type = "submit" value="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Also I guess You should be considering the following points for your implementation, If You want user Id and answer Id to be increases and all the questions to printed

1. Also incrementing variables answerID and UserID does not have any
   impact as they are initialised to 1 every time at the function call
   , Instead track them in request variable
2. It will print you the last question only,Have out.println("Dr.Anna : "+ ques); inside the for each loop of the list

Comment: it's working.. Thank you but how do i can make it the userID and AnswerId can increase? i try to declare int USER_ID; but it cannot be declare